# Align cards of CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, alignment, cardlayout

I have a CardLayout with several "cards" into it. The thing is that not every card has the same size, so the main panel takes the size of the biggest card.

The problem is that the biggest card shows fine, but when I show a littlest card, its content is aligned at the top-left corner, which is a normal behaviour I think.

But in my GUI it looks awful (since the cards are in the EAST part of the JFrame), so how could I tell the CardLayout to push everything at the right side of there is an empty space ?

Thank you !

Comment: Each card will,position it's components based on the requirements of the layout manager. What layout managers are you using for the cards?

Comment: I am using a GridBagLayout, that's why I can't manage to get it working.